# In Oracle, is using Sequences for surrogate primary keys considered standard

Tags: oracle10g, oracle11g, sequences

**Caveats:**

Let me first clarify that this is not a question about whether to use surrogates primary keys or not.

Also, this is NOT a related to identities (SQL Server) / Sequences (Oracle) and their pros / cons. I did get a fair bit of idea about that thanks to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282787/primary-keys-in-oracle-and-sql-server), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948644/database-key-id-design-ideas-surrogate-key-primary-key-etc) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707657/picking-the-best-primary-key-numbering-system/718200)

**Question:**

I come from a SQL Server background and have always used identity columns as surrogate primary keys for most tables.

Based on my knowledge of Oracle, I find that the nearest equivalent in Oracle are SEQUENCES which can be used to simulate something similar to Identity in SQL server.

***As I am new to Oracle and my database has 100+ tables, the main thing that i am concerned about :-***

Considering i have to create a sequence for each table in Oracle (*almost*), would this be the standard accepted implementation for simulating Identity or is there a better / easier way to achieve this kind of implementation in Oracle?

Are there any specific GOTCHA's related to having **so many** sequences in Oracle?

The system supports both Oracle 10G and 11G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Considering i have to create a
>   sequence for each table in Oracle
>   (almost), would this be the standard
>   accepted implementation for simulating
>   Identity or is there a better / easier
>   way to achieve this kind of
>   implementation in Oracle?

Yes, it is very typical in Oracle to create a sequence for each table.  It is possible to use the same sequence for several tables, but you run the risk of making it a bottleneck by using a single sequence for many/all tables: [see this AskTom q/a](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2985886242221)

> Are there any specific GOTCHA's
>   related to having so many sequences in
>   Oracle?

None that I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

100+ tables is not very many. I routinely work on databases with several hundred sequences, one for each table. The more the merrier.

It's even conceivable to have more sequences than tables - unlike identity columns in other DBMSs, sequences can be used for more than just creating surrogate key values.

An alternative is to use GUIDs - in Oracle you can call SYS_GUID to generate unique values.

A good article, followed by comments with pros and cons for both approaches: http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2009/12/sysguid.html

Comment: The advice is reassuring as it confirms that i am not doing something silly due to my inexperience with the product. Appreciate it. +1. Thanks!!